# python 3 how to compress a dictionary with tuple keys representing overlapping coordinates

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key is a tuple representing line y coordinates (y0, y1) where y0 = bottom of line y coordinate and y1 = top of line y coordinate

```
data = { (622, 633): 'text1', (604, 619) : 'text2', (596, 633) : 'text3', (577, 587) : 'text4', (551, 587) : 'text5'  }
```

I want to be able to "compress" the dictionary so that all items with tuple corrdinates that overlap are combined together under the tuple key with the biggest y0, y1 range. So the above dictionary should end up like:

```
data = { (596, 633) : 'text1 text2 text3', (551, 587) : 'text4 text5' }
```

I'm a newbie to python and am scratching my head on this one and would appreciate a nod in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do if they overlap but none is fully contained in another, like `(1, 5)` and `(3, 8)`?  Do you want to create a new key for their union `(1, 8)`?

Comment: Why is text2 grouped (596,633) if its coordinates are (604,619)?

Comment: Sorry, no attempts so far as I don't know where to start.

Comment: text2 is grouped in (596,633) as the range 604 - 619 (604,619) is wholly contained within the range 596 - 633.  And the question about (1, 5) and (3, 8)  - as they overlap then they should be combined into (1,8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like:

```
# Returns True if point yt is in the range (y0, y1) inclusive
def _in(yt, y): return y[0] <= yt <= y[1]

# Returns True if either segment intersects (or is contained in the other), False otherwise
def intersects(s1, s2): return _in(s1[0], s2) or _in(s1[1], s2) or _in(s2[0], s1) or _in(s2[1], s1)

# Returns an (i,e) tuple for each element e of lst that "intersects" (see prev. function) list lst
#   i is index of element e in lst
def find_intersections(s, lst): return [(i,e) for (i,e) in enumerate(lst) if intersects(s,e)]

# Returns a 2-tuple containing the minimum and maximum of the input segments s1, s2
def merge(s1, s2): return (min(s1[0], s2[0]), max(s1[1], s2[1]))
# Note: The functions _in and merge assume that y0,y1 are sorted, ascending

data = { (622, 633): 'text1', (604, 619) : 'text2', (596, 633) : 'text3', (577, 587) : 'text4', (551, 587) : 'text5'  }
new_data = {}

lst = list(data.keys())
while len(lst):
    rng = lst.pop()

    keys = [rng,]
    while True:
        updated = False
        for (i,match) in find_intersections(rng, lst):
            updated = True
            keys.append(match)
            rng = merge(rng, match)
            lst.pop(i)
        if not updated: break

    new_data[rng] = ' '.join(sorted(data[k] for k in keys))

print(new_data)      # {(551, 587): 'text4 text5', (596, 633): 'text1 text2 text3'}
```

*Edit: Some tweaks made for Python3*

Comment: Thanks jedwards that's a great help. It is working on my test data and has given me some ideas how to proceed.